# WPF Style for Control Library

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, wpf-controls, themes

I have a library (`Styles.DLL`) which contains a collection of keyed WPF `Styles`.

I have a class library (`Module.DLL`) which contains a number of `Windows` and `UserControls` which can be shared across various applications. I use the keyed `Styles` defined in `Styles.DLL` to create implicit `Styles` for the various `Controls` used on these `Windows` and `UserControls` e.g. `Button` or `ComboBox`.

I then have an application (`App.EXE`) in which I use the `Windows` defined in `Module.DLL`. I merge the required `ResourceDictionaries` from `Styles.DLL` in the `App.xaml` of `App.EXE`.

This all works.

---

My question is: *How can I remove the dictionary merging from App.xaml in the hosting application and include it in Module.DLL without having to merge the dictionaries into each Window's resources?*

I guess I'm looking for something like an `app.xaml` file but for a class library...

Comment: hmmm... generic.xaml is a dictionary so just merge dictionaries at the top of generic.xaml and it might work, try it out

Comment: just create a ressource dictionary in which you merge all the files and then your just include this ressource dictionary in your app.xaml then you only have one ressource dictionary to include

Comment: As the question states, I'm trying to move away from using App.xaml. I don't want to have to merge the resources for every application which uses the module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a method that clears the current Dictionaries and merge the ones I want. Actually, the "Clear" has to be set inside at the method invocation, here's an example:

```
    void AddResourceDictionary(string source)
    {
        ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(source, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) as ResourceDictionary;
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
    }
```

Implementing a custom Theme/Skin/Resource:

```
        private void ThemeNameHere()
    {
        Application.Current.Resources.Clear();

        AddResourceDictionary("Computar.Wpf;component/Style/MyStyle.xaml");
        ....

    }
```

It's been very helpful!

Comment: Yes, this is equivalent to what I came up with so I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to solve this using `XAML` only. My solution was to merge the required `ResourceDictionaries` into the `Application` object in code using the following:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Styles.DLL;component/Styles.xaml")
});
```

Hopefully this will help someone who has a similar issue.